# Semantic-UI / ReactJS | Use DropDown as group

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `Semantic-UI/ReactJS` and want to use [DropDown](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-search-query) component as `group` but there is not such option, but I googled, and find a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLoanbwb/3/) that provide this *but* in standalone `semantic ui` not for `reactjs`, how can I use dropdown as group?

```
<Dropdown
    id="Province"
    search selection clearable
    options={this.state.ProvinceData && this.state.ProvinceData.map(v => {
        return {
            key: v.id,
            text: v.name,
            value: v.id
        }
    })}
    onChange={this.getProvince}
    placeholder="-- Choose --"
    value={this.state.provinceValue}
    noResultsMessage={'Not Found!'}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown component with children can not have "selection" property and that is the problem. Although You can "hack" it.
*Note that this is not a "clean" solution, but visually makes difference.*

Let's say your "options" array of objects is like this:

```
[
  {
    key: v.id,
    text: v.name,
    value: v.id
  },
  ...
]
```

You can create a simple React Component and style it as You wish:

```
const OptGroupHeader = props => {
  const { header } = props
    return (
      <div>
        <hr />
        <strong><i>{ header }</i></strong>
       <hr />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Now what you can do is provide it as a disabled option where you want to use your header.

```
options.splice(x, 0, {
  key: 'key - xxx', 
  value: 'value', 
  text: (<OptGroupHeader header='My Fancy Header' />), 
  disabled: true
})
```

A component inside the "text" property will be rendered.

Answer (score -1):

**Use `<Dropdown.Header />` and `<Dropdown.Divider />`**

```
<Dropdown
    id="Province"
    search selection clearable
    onChange={this.getProvince}
    placeholder="-- Choose --"
    value={this.state.provinceValue}
    noResultsMessage={'Not Found!'}
    <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Header icon='tags' content='Group 1' />
        <Dropdown.Item text='Text 1' />
        <Dropdown.Item text='Text 2' />
        <Dropdown.Item text='Text 3' />
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Header icon='tags' content='Group 2' />
        <Dropdown.Item text='Text 4' />
        <Dropdown.Item text='Text 5' />
        <Dropdown.Item text='Text 6' />
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Just iterate your options as above `jsx`